# Use Where Clause on navigation property. Many-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I have been looking through other examples on SO and I am still unable to resolve this.

I have the following model structure

```
 public class Event
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public ICollection<EventCategory> EventCategories{ get; set; }
    }

 public class Category
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public ICollection<EventCategory> EventCategories{ get; set; }
    }

 public class EventCategory
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int EventID{ get; set; }
        public Event Event{ get; set; }
        public int CategoryID{ get; set; }
        public Category Category{ get; set; }
    }
```

From my Events controller I am trying to use a LINQ query to only show Events where the CategoryID is equal to 1 but i keep on coming into errors with my WHERE clause I think.

UPDATE:

I have been trying multiple queries but at present it is

```
    var eventsContext = _context.Events
            .Include(e => e.EventCategories)
            .Include(e=>e.EventCategories.Select(ms => ms.Category))
            .Where(e=>e.ID==1)
            .Take(15)
            .OrderByDescending(o => o.StartDate);
```

This is the error I get

[image: Error Messsage]

TIA

Comment: Can you please share your LINQ Query and error?

Comment: Does your ICollections have a name?

Comment: Sorry i typed in the classes wrong by mistake. I have updated my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the lambda passed to `Include` must be a model expression. Specifically, that means you cannot use something like `Select`. If you're trying to include `EventCategories.Category`, then you should actually do:

```
.Include(e => e.EventCategories).ThenInclude(ms => ms.Category)
```

That will fix your immediate error. The next issue is that the way in which you're attempting to query the category ID is incorrect. The lamdas don't carry over from one clause to the next. In other words, when you're doing `Where(e => e.ID == 1)`, `e` is `Event`, not `Category`. The fact that you just included `Category` doesn't limit the where clause to that context. Therefore, what you actually need is:

```
.Where(e => e.EventCategories.Any(c => c.CategoryID == 1))
```

For what it's worth, you could also write that as:

```
.Where(e => e.EventCategories.Any(c => c.Category.ID == 1))
```

Notice the `.` between `Category` and `ID`. Now this where clause requires joins to be made between all of `Event`, `EventCategories`, *and* `Category`, which then means you don't actually need your `Include(...).ThenInclude(...)` statement, since all this does is tell EF to make the same JOINs it's already making. I will still usually do the includes explicitly, though, as otherwise, if your where clause were to change in some future iteration, you may end up no longer implicitly including everything you actually want included. Just food for thought.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the in depth explanation. Works perfectly